# Role of "etc" directory in project tree

Tags: java, eclipse

What is the role of "etc" directory in a project ? We use "lib" to add all the jars or libraries, "src" to place source code and "build" to place jars/ear/wars/rpms.

Comment: Which project tree specifies that there should be an "etc" directory?

Comment: None. Current project I'm working on has it. Before delving into its details thought it would be good have an idea of what is its purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the developer.  Could be resources that are loaded by application.  Could be resources that developer explicitly didn't want to be included in deployable.  Check build script (pom.xml etc.) to see what happens to it.